# create a label for text inputs that is diffrenet from value

Tags: html

for example i have a disabled input that holds a time span, but i want to show it to user in a friendly format. just like select element, the option with in can hold a value that is different from what is displayed

```
<select><option value=1>Label is there</option></select>
```

can it be done with input ?

something like

```
<input type='text' value='<?=$time?>' label='<?=date('c',$time);?>' />
```

P.s: im not asking for a place holder.

currently im doing

```
<label for="app_time">Time</label>
<input type="hidden" value="2013-04-27 15:40:00" name="app_time">
<input type="text" value="27 Apr 13, 03:40" Disabled>
```

is there any other method ?

Comment: You'd probably be better off storing the value in a hidden element and the label in a plain text box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap an input in the `label` tag.

```
<label>Text for the input <input type="text" name="yourInput"></label>
```

Or you can reference the input from a `label` tag.

```
<label for="yourInput">Text for the input</label>
<input type="text" name="yourInput" id="yourInput">
```

You can add styling to the label element and it aids people using assistive technology as it links the description with the form element.

Comment: I think that he is not asking for this type of label.

Answer (score 1):

Not in the way you are asking, however you could always try it with a hidden element holding the real value...

Try;

```
<input type="text" value="<?=date('c',$time);?>" name="dummytime" />
<input type="hidden" value="<?=$time;?>" name="realtime" />
```

So to get $time it would be `$_POST['realtime']` and to get the formatted date value it would be `$_POST['dummytime']`.

Comment: This is correct, however, the name for the text input is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

No, not in the way you're asking.  The `value` of the text input is what is displayed within it.

As an alternative you could use a hidden input with the actual value, and then put the label in the text input

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to handle converting the date to a timestamp on the server side. You'll need to ensure the submitted text is able to be converted to a timestamp, however, and show the user an error if not. There is not a built-in way for JavaScript to convert some given user-inputted string to a computer-readable date format.

Edit: I'm assuming you want the actual value to match whatever the user enters, not a static timestamp. If you want to submit a static value regardless of the user's input, simply use a hidden input (`<input type="hidden">`) and a secondary text input that you can ignore.